# Manually Searching DNS

Tags: 15.10, dns

I am trying to track down a host in our network but only know part of it's name. I know it would be in DNS but I don't want to have to sign into those servers and look through the config. Is there an easy way to just search my DNS on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nbtscan terminal program to find NetBIOS names on a network.

Open up a terminal and run this command to install nbtscan.

```
sudo apt-get install nbtscan
```

**nbtscan usage :**

Say your network router ip address is 192.168.1.1

`sudo nbtscan [Your scan range]` Can either be single IP like `192.168.1.1` or range of addresses in one of two forms: `192.168.1.1/25` or `192.168.1.1-255`

Example of nbtscan command and results of scan.

```
sudo nbtscan 192.168.1.1/24
[sudo] password for neil: 
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.1.1/24

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.0 Sendto failed: Permission denied
192.168.1.69     ASUS             <server>  ASUS             00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.1.255   Sendto failed: Permission denied
192.168.1.212    FTP              <server>  FTP              00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.1.159    PXE              <server>  PXE              00:00:00:00:00:00
neil@ASUS:~$
```